# Getting 'Your input was invalid' error while obtaining an API Key for Google Maps API v2

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am doing a sample application for Google map. I am using the same sample code which is given at `/extras/google/google_play_services/samples/maps` in android directory.

I am trying to create an API key to use in sample application. I am referring [Create and Obtain API Key for Google Maps Android API v2 service](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/12/create-and-obtain-api-key-for-google.html) and [Google Maps Android API v2 docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start), and I am getting an error on Google console page.

After putting MD5 and package name (as `CF:7C:E3:40:8E:SA:2B:31:E8:E7:ED:31:7A:8A:D7:46;com.test.myapp`) I am getting ***"Your input was invalid"*** error. I am doing all the steps (till this error) right (as my given URLS say), but don't know why this error is going on.

Please help me to solve this error.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**You are putting MD5 fingerprint of your keystore, but this api require SHA1.**

Refer this image.

[image]

Comment: yes you are right dude! I was doing a mistake. Thank you very much.

Comment: Thanks, I was doing same mistake. Now ok.

Comment: it gives you the command to run right there in the dialog box

Comment: I double checked my output and that I was using the SHA1 field values and still got the same error. Did anyone else still encounter this and were you able to determine if it was something else?

Comment: I had a space between the SHA1 value ending semicolon and my package name. Removed it and created the key successfully. :/

Answer (score 2):

First go to jdk folder bin form there type the below command

```
keytool.exe -v -list  -keystore "C:\Users\NewPC\.android\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android
```

you will get detail output of all keys including sha1 finger print then follow the steps in google api website.

sha1 looks like this

```
B9:BC:1A:87:5A:9E:29:8A:DE:BD:41:19:63:A1:FD:60:04:EA:83:4A
```

Answer (score -2):

Google now stopped API key generation you can use new V3 version of google api and , with your account you can enable all service what ever you want.

Comment: What? Can you refer any link please? I think V1 is deprecated not v2.

Comment: Google map V3 is for java script, for android v2 is latest, and if i am wrong then please post v3 link so i can update my knowledge